# Issue with the Polly retry inside loop

Tags: c#, .net, polly

Iam using Polly retry policy to retry while throwing exception.Here Iam  trying to use that retry policy inside a loop.So while executing the foreach loop if it throws any exception then Polly retries.This part works fine.But i want to continue with the next iteration inside the loop after retry.But it throws final exception after 2 retries and returns to calling method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RetryPolicy();
    }

    private static void RetryPolicy()
    {
        try
        {
            var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().Retry(2);
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            list.AddRange(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 });
            foreach(var item in list)
            {
               retryPolicy.Execute(() => Calculate(item));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private static void Calculate(int j)
    {
       int a = 10;
       int b = j;
       var c = a / b;
    }
```

Here in first iteration it gives error and after 2 retries i want to return to the loop and continue with other items inside for each loop.Is there any way i can achieve this with Polly.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Your `try/catch` is in the wrong place - it should be inside the loop. That way, when Polly throws an exception after the final retry, the exception is caught and handled (please don't use empty catches), then the loop continues.

But there's an even better way: remove the try/catch and use ExecuteAndCapture() - this returns a result that indicates whether there was an overall success or failure. Then do something with it:

```
private static void RetryPolicy()
{
    var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().Retry(2);
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.AddRange(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
       var policyResult = retryPolicy.ExecuteAndCapture(() => Calculate(item));
       if (policyResult.Outcome != OutcomeType.Successful) 
       {
           // do something remedial. then the loop can continue.
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help it helped me a lot.
Was working on a POC.Have on more query .Can i use this same logic if i am using Parallel.ForEach. In my case i need to make calls to wcf service and update results in DB.So would like to execute this in parellel on different threads.Let me know whether its fine if i replace foreach with Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: You can definitely use the same logic in Parallel.ForEach, but there's a catch: Mixing WCF with PLINQ is not trivial and you are likely to run into issues outside the scope of this question (unless you've already done it before and you're just adding Polly to existing logic). Hope that helps!